# Are the complementary base pairs known as genes?

Tags: dna, chromosome

In my text book ,it is written that a chromosome has 1000s of genes and it is distributed throughout the chromatids except in the centromere. But we know that the chromosomes have DNAs inside them which have complementary base pairs. Then are these base pairs known as genes??

Comment: A chromatid is a single hundred of million bases DNA molecules, glued to its complement and a chromosome is two identical copies of that chromatid.  You might want to look at https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/NC_000001.11?from=1000&to=100000 you can see that the region 10875..13410 encodes a gene named DDX11L1 whose sequence is given below. So the genes are those kind of annotated pieces of the chromosome sequence, mainly dedicated to understanding the mRNA whence the proteins that will be produced from it.

Comment: what do you think is meant by "complementary base pairs"? Have you researched this term at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't assume a chromosome to be some X-shaped box that contains DNA inside it and DNA as a container of genes.

DNA, genes, Chromatid, Chromosomes are just different names at different levels of the same thing.

In molecular biology, you'll find multiple definitions of certain terms because as new insights are gained by any researcher, the definition gets modified. So one has to always make their concept clear so that they don't get confused between the same yet uniquely different terms.

So, Let's first look at how different their definitions can be:

> **DNA** is a [molecule](https://www.cancer.gov/publications/dictionaries/genetics-dictionary/def/dna) inside cells that contains the genetic information responsible for the development and function of an organism. DNA molecules allow this information to be passed from one generation to the next. DNA is made up of a double-stranded helix held together by weak hydrogen bonds between purine-pyrimidine nucleotide base pairs: adenine (A) paired with thymine (T), and guanine (G) paired with cytosine (C). Also called deoxyribonucleic acid.

> [**GENE**](https://www.nature.com/articles/39166), For many years the HGNC has maintained the definition of a gene as “a DNA segment that contributes to phenotype/function. In the absence of demonstrated function a gene may be characterized by sequence, transcription, or homology”. As there is still no universally agreed alternative we continue to use this definition.

> **Chromosome** is a highly coiled structure of DNA molecule. Often observed in X-shaped only. Along with DNA, some proteins are also make up chromosomes.

But Why does DNA need to be coiled tightly into chromosomes?

DNA double helix is like a telephone wire. If length is to be measured, it will go beyond 60 miles. Some even say it can make a trip to the moon more than 150,000 times. Such a long DNA molecule is not only the part of each organism's cell nucleus but also it's invisible to the naked eye. This happens just because of the high packaging and coiling of this long DNA molecule.

Let's see the diagram to get an idea.[image]

At the bottom  of the diagram there is a sequence of nucleotides (ATGC) in different combinations. This can be considered as a gene if it codes for certain protein which is required for the growth or any other function of the body.

Returning back to your question, Complimentary base pairs are not genes.

Genes are the segments of DNA which is a long sequence of nucleotide base pairs that code for any protein or RNA transcript that contributes to any trait/phenotype/function of an individual.

With the tight packaging of DNA double helix along with help of packaging proteins(Histones and Non-histones), the chromatid and chromosomes are made. The packaging of DNA to chromosomes is highly controlled and is a whole different topic in itself.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, even in the centromere region, complementary base pairs are found, so, if base pairs were to be known as genes, then genes would also be present in the centromeric region.

Secondly, *Genes* are functional units of *DNA* made of one or more *codons* which store *information* to make *protein* which gives an organism a certain characteristics.

Basically, DNA is made of two complementary strands of nitrogenous bases [ Adenine(***A***), Thymine(***T***), Guanine(***G***) and Cytosine(***C***) ]. [Read](https://openstax.org/books/concepts-biology/pages/9-1-the-structure-of-dna)/ [Watch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o_-6JXLYS-k)

Now that you know the structure of DNA, realize that information may be stored by the order in which the Nitrogenous bases are placed. Exactly this strategy is used by your cells, to build your body, in other words, you.

I am not writing about the process by which that information is interpreted by your body, since that is beyond the scope of the question, still, you can [Read](https://openstax.org/books/concepts-biology/pages/9-3-transcription)/ [Watch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gG7uCskUOrA) about it.